# Why does this site not have a mobile style the same as other SE sites?

Tags: feature-request, design

If I visit any other Stack Exchange site from my phone, I see an easy-to-read version designed specifically for mobile. But when I visit boardgames.stackexchange.com from my phone, I see what looks like the normal desktop view; but because my phone screen is small; everything is tiny and it is hard to read and use.

I would guess that other sites simply have custom styling to support mobile; but they all seem to look the same as each other; so it seems like there is some sort of default mobile view provided by SE that Boardgames doesn’t have.

Examples of sites that look good on mobile: movies, philosophy, math, cooking, gaming... actually every site I’ve checked except Boardgames.

Comment: I see the mobile site. If you scroll to the bottom of the page you see, is there a link that says "Mobile"? If there is, clicking it should make you see the mobile site view.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Oh wow... I guess at some point in the past I clicked "full site", and it seems to remember that setting in a cookie or something. For most sites, clicking that link would only keep you in desktop mode for the current window or session. Thanks!

Comment: Unsure if I should delete this. It might be helpful if anyone else has this same issue.

Comment: I would suggest just expanding your comment about what happened into an answer, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Stack Exchange sites have the ability to switch between mobile view and desktop view. While in desktop view; there is a link to go to mobile at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

The trick is that once you enter desktop view; this is saved, presumably in a cookie, so that you will always see this view from that browser, until you click the link to go back to the mobile view.

Comment: Yep. Though, as a note based on personal experience, those cookies do expire from time to time, so sometimes it will revert to mobile view.